How to get data from another model in DetailView
I'm trying to get objects from two models using DetailView. First, I set urls.py:
from django.urls import path
from . views import RetiroListView, RetiroDetailView
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('post/<int:pk>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post-detail'),
    path('post/', views.post, name='post-post'),
]

Here are my models:
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.

class Post(models.Model):
    
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.OneToOneField(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    comment=models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Tags(models.Model):
    post = models.OneToOneField(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    comment=models.CharField(max_length=100)

and the detail view:
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post

Now, in my template, I can use:
{{ object.title }}
To access my post information but, I need to get some info from the other tables, in this view. I know I have to overwrite the get_context_data method, but I don't know how.

Can you tell me exactly what parts you want to bring from other tables?

yeah, for comment it's the comment variable and for for tags it's also the comment variable

#1 set queryset variable
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
  # model = Post
  queryset = {custom queryset}

#2 override get_queryset method
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
  # model = Post
  def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):
    return {custom queryset}


You can access related object data in the template without get_context_data. For example {{ object.comment.comment }} will render the comment text for the Post model object. Please note that object.comment refers to the Comment model object.
But if I understand the idea correctly, I would advise looking into ForeignKey instead of OneToOneField. Here's a good overview - OneToOneField() vs ForeignKey() in Django.


yeah, for comment it's the comment variable and for for tags it's also the comment variable

I didn't understand this exactly, so I interpreted it as bringing comments and tags related to Post.
It can be implemented through a query set without the need to use the get_context_data method suggested by the questioner.
views.py
from django.views.generic import DetailView

from .models import Post

# Create your views here.
from django.views.generic import DetailView

from .models import Post

# Create your views here.
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
  template_name = "posts/post-detail.html"
  context_object_name = "post"
  model = Post

As shown above, PostDetailView renders a post-detail.html template, and the Post object delivered from that template can be accessed with the value "post" which is the context_object_name.
post-detail.html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>{{ post.title }}</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
    <div>{{ post.content }}</div>
    <div>{{ post.comment.comment }}</div>
    <div>{{ post.tags.comment }}</div>
  </body>
</html>

That's why you can access a single post delivered by PostDetailView when you use post as a template variable in a post-detail template.
And the comment and tags objects connected to the post can also be accessed directly from the post object.

post.conmment.(comment field)
post.tags.(tags field)

This approach is possible because You connected to OneToOneField.
Please refer to this document for more reasons!
And I have one question.
If you connect the comments and tags to OneToOneField, you have one comment, tag per Post. Is this the expected part?

correct, I didn't want to add many comments per posts, I do know that to add many comments it would be a one to many relationship in my model
